# nodejs model updateOne does NOT give same result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Trying to update a document in mongodb using the following method :

```
module.exports.addAcc = function(id , acc, callback) {
    let strAcc  = escape(JSON.stringify(acc, null, 4));

    let pushAcc =  '{'+ ' $push :'+ '{ "pf.acc" : '  +strAcc + '}}' ;
    let query = '{ "userid": ' + id + '}'; 

    console.log('udpate <<',query,',' ,pushAcc, '>>');   <=====

    Api.updateOne(query, pushAcc, {upsert: false},  callback);

};
```

it does give the following result :

```
{
"ok": 0,
"n": 0,
"nModified": 0
}
```

And When I catch what's in the console.log line and replace  it in the Api.updateOne line,  like this:

```
Api.updateOne({ "userid": 1197} , { $push :{ "pf.acc" : {"accid":1496998168,"accbr":65875}}}, {upsert: false}, callback);
```

it WORKS !!

```
{
"n": 1,
"nModified": 1,
"ok": 1
}
```

any idea why is that ?

/KOul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said here is how I have modified the piece of code :

```
module.exports.addAcc = function(id , acc, callback) {
    let strAcc  = escape(JSON.stringify(acc, null, 4));


    let query = {
        "userid": id
    }
    let pushAcc = {
        $push : { "pf.acc" : strAcc }
    }

    console.log('udpate <<',query,',' ,pushAcc, '>>');

    Api.updateOne(query, pushAcc, {upsert: false},  callback);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You realize when calling Api.updateOne you are passing string params instead of json objects.

Make following changes.

**EDIT :**

```
let pushAcc = {$push :{"pf.acc": strAcc}};
let query = {"userid": id}; 
Api.updateOne(query, pushAcc, {upsert: false},  callback);
```

Comment: I got this : SyntaxError: Unexpected token $ in JSON at position 2. apparently the parse it did not go for $push

Comment: I set the query and pushAcc in json format and it works like a charm

Comment: Edited the required changes. Please accept the solution if its working or upload the one you have, so that anyone else looking for same gets the idea.